# Manipulation json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I have a JavaScript array object that looks like something below:

```
var Array = [{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2","foo3":"bar3","foo4":"bar4","foo5":"bar5","foo6":"bar6","foo7":"bar7"},
{"foo1":"bar5","foo2":"bar6","foo3":"bar7","foo4":"bar8","foo5":"bar9","foo6":"bar10","foo7":"bar10"}]
```

I want this array to be converted to a JSON formatted string for serializing which looks something like. I am using `JSON.stringify` for serializing which should give me the resulting 
string like the one below:

```
'"fooAry" : [{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2","foo3":"bar3","foo4":"bar4"},
{"foo1":"bar5","foo2":"bar6","foo3":"bar7","foo4":"bar8"}]'
```

As you can see there are two things here:

1. Getting rid of the last 3 elements of the key values pairs inside the array
2. appending the key `fooAry` to the resulting JSON string.

Comment: The key / value pairs aren't really inside the array, that is, they are, but more importantly they are inside the object, and as order is not guaranteed in an object, just removing the three last entrys might not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Also, don't use `Array` as your var name, it can seriously mess with other code.

Comment: @adeneo The scenario which i am working guarantees me the order of the last 3 three key/value pairs and hence I want to manually remove it.

Comment: @bfavaretto That's just an example.

Comment: @Raghu What adeneo meant is that a JS plain object is an unordered data structure.

Comment: @Raghu - That's pretty freaking amazing, as an object per definition in javascript is an unordered collection of properties ?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Makes sense, but how i would like to know how to get rid of last 3 key /value from each object within the array

Comment: removing something would be as easy as `delete Array[0].foo5`, but again, you'll have to name the keys, as there is no special order.

Comment: You are mistaken. There is an order to an object's properties when iterating over them, and that's the order of their insertion. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/pUzES/1/).

Comment: @EZSlaver Exactly..That how i am getting the my array of objects with the same sequence !!

Comment: @EZSlaver: The specification explicitly states that any ordering is implementation dependant. Just because you can make a demo that works right now, doesn't necessarily mean it works that way in all browsers, or that it'll continue to work that way in the next version of your browser.

Comment: What Crazy Trains said. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4 - *The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.*

Comment: @EZSlaver - that's what ***most browsers*** will default to, but there really is no guaranteed order, so relying on that will cause you a shitload of problems, trust me, I've tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G7sKP/ <- just for fun !

Comment: Never mind what how browsers can implement it. If it works in **all** the major browsers, than it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you really could guarantee the elements order in the object:

```
var a = [
    {"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2","foo3":"bar3","foo4":"bar4","foo5":"bar5","foo6":"bar6","foo7":"bar7"},
    {"foo1":"bar5","foo2":"bar6","foo3":"bar7","foo4":"bar8","foo5":"bar9","foo6":"bar10","foo7":"bar10"}
];

// Object.keys polyfill
if (!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
    var ret=[], p;
    for (p in o){
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p)){
            ret.push(p);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

function removeLast3(obj){   
    var ks = Object.keys(obj).slice(0, -3);
    var newobj = {}, k, i;
    for (i=0; k=ks[i]; i++){
        newobj[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return newobj;
}

var newA = [removeLast3(a[0]), removeLast3(a[1])];
var strA = '"fooAry": ' + JSON.stringify(newA);
```